# How to change a bibliography given in BibTeX file to the LaTeX format (i.e., with 'bibitems')?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the bibliography of a paper in BibTeX format, that is, I have the paper which then says `\printbibliography` at the end, with a corresponding .bib file separate to the main paper .tex file. I want to change this so that I have the article (or just the bibliography) in the LaTeX format, i.e., as something like `\begin{thebibliography} \bibitem{X} ... \end{thebibliography}`.

Can anyone advise me on how to do this? Sorry if this is a very basic or stupid question; I'm not used to much of LaTeX.

Comment: With regular `bibtex`, you would first compile the document, which would create an `.aux` file. You would then run `bibtex` on that `.aux` file, and it would create a `.bbl` file, and that `.bbl` file would have the `thebibliography` environment with the `\bibitems` in it. However, you mentioned `\printbibliography`, which suggests suggests biblatex is being used, not regular bibtex, and it does not use the `thebibliography` environment. The `biber` program typically used for biblatex run in the same way does produce a `.bbl` file, but it'll be in a different format.

Comment: So I guess it depends on why you need the the markup for the `thebibliography` environment whether or not what is produced by biber instead would suffice, or whether you need to switch the document to use regular bibtex and a regular bibtex style file instead of a biblatex one.

Comment: Hi @frabjous, it simply has to be in a format that has bibitems--do you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: If there is already a BibTeX style compatible with your needs, it would be very easy. If there isn't, then it won't be so easy. You never mentioned what style you're using, so I don't know. Also, do you know if the `.bib` file contains extra entries not cited in the paper (and do you need them?) The best thing would be to post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that shows all packages and relevant commands related to the bibliography.